# Including jar files into library project

Tags: android, jar, libraries, external-dependencies

I am developing small library for android application. My library having some dependencies for that i want to include some external jar file into my library project so that user of library need not be worry about library dependencies. I know how to include external jar files in normal android project. But i don't know how to include external jar files into my android library. Can any one to do this.

What is the proper way to do that. Need help. Thank you..

Comment: A library project can include a JAR library.
You can develop a library project that itself includes a JAR library, however you need to manually edit the dependent application project's build path and add a path to the JAR file. More info @ http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Comment: hi raghunandan can you please explain how to do that.I am not able to get this solution

Comment: right click on your library project. go to  java build path. Choose Libraries and jar to your library project by clicking add jars

Comment: Thank you raghunandan for replay but this is normal way in which we include jars to our android project. But what about manually edit the dependent application project's build path and add a path to the JAR file. Is it same thing which your are explaining.

Comment: why don't you give it a try and come back and inform

Comment: I tried what's mentioned in the comment. worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Each jar file is a zipped file and can be opened by `winrar` application. Extract the content of those jar files ( Folders and *.class files ) and add them into your jar file.

Comment: HI breceivemail thank you for relay. I will try your solution. But is there any way to direct include my jar file inside my library. because my library having lot of dependencies then is it good way to copy all data from all jar files and put it in to my library? Thank you for replay

Comment: @nilkash I do not know any other solution unfortunately.

Comment: thank you for help. Can you read connect on my question of raghunandan. He is saying its possible to add external jar library to a library. But I am not able to get that solution. can you please help me.

Comment: @nilkash **I think** his answer is not related to your question

Comment: @breceivemail why do you think the answer is not related to the question. Check this http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple. You can select the files that you want to export as jar. Check following image[image]

Comment: Where can we find this window in eclipse?

Comment: Right click on project-> Export. Here under java select jar file then click next. U will see this screen. There you can choose which file to include in jar.